# Minimization of a summation and a norm

Tags: optimization, summation

I have been trying to figure out how to minimize

$$\|y-x\|_2^2 +\mu\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (y_{i+1}-y_i)^2$$

where $y$ is a vector and $x$ is a noisy data set vector by putting it into the form of

$$\|Ay-b\|_2^2$$

and minimizing from there. I understand how to deal with the left half of the equation but the summation is what's throwing me off.

Comment: Are you trying to find a value of $\mu$ that minimizes this with $x$ and $y$ fixed? Or maybe a value of $y$ that minimizes this with $x$ and $\mu$ fixed?

Comment: I want to solve for y essentially, I have x as a noisy function and then depending on a set mu value, I would like to find the values of y that show a smoother function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective function can be written as
$$
f(y) = \| y - x\|_2^2 + \mu \| Dy \|_2^2
$$
where
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & & \ddots & \ddots& & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The gradient of $f$ is
$$
\nabla f(y) = 2(y - x) + 2\mu D^T Dy.
$$
To minimize $f$, you can set the gradient equal to $0$ and solve for $y$.

Comment: what if I do not know what the D matrix is? say I only know mu and x, I see that solving for y gives $$y=\frac{x}{\mu D^T D}$$

Comment: @PineRun But you do know $D$. I edited the answer to write $D$ explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is the shift operator (where $a_{i, i+1} = 0,$ and $a_{i,j}=0$ otherwise.)